# RFID brand: ACS; model: ACR122

Tags: c#, asp.net, csb

Does anyone know what are the codes in writing and reading of data in the [Mifare 1K card](http://www.nfc-reader.com/acr122.php)?? we uses c#.

Answer (score 7):

from [DreamInCode](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic93400.htm), check the comment by [Goethals](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showuser=202914):

> "Pretty hard to find some decent
> documentation on Smardcards isn't it?
> Had some rough time trying to get it
> work too some time ago. (Did not get
> it to work completely yet, ran out of
> time)
>
> The best way i found as of yet is to
> invoke the Winscard.dll api.
>
> The following articles contain some
> valuable information on how to:
>
> http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Smart-Cards-in-.NET/
> http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Smart-C...in-.NET-Part-2/
> http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Smart-Cards-in-NET-Part-3/
>
> Its C#, but that should not be a big
> problem.
>
> Some random info from the following
> blog helped me too: (Contains
> explenation for some of the error
> codes.)
>
> https://github.com/geersch/MonitoringSmartcardReader
>
> On the MSDN website, there is also
> some information regarding
> Winscard.dll. (Do a search on Smard
> Card or SCard, you should find some
> articles.)
>
> I also found some documentation on the
> website of OmniKey. (The manifacturer
> of the Smard Card Reader I am using.)
>
> http://www.omnikey.com/index.php?id=68
>
> The omnikey website is often down
> though.
>
> Hope this helps you out a bit. Cheers!
> "

also you can check out (this in C) the [RFID C Library](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/rfid/)

I've also just found out that [mathias4u](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/member.php?s=d0bc7f527cd06f505efece5f58021ec3&u=427184) has developed a A[CR122 plug-in that supports the mifare 1k](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=166281), you can [download](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Tools/Plug-ins/Enablers/Series_40_Nokia_6212_NFC_SDK/Features.xhtml) it [here](http://www.ubuntuschneider.dnsdojo.org/nfc/ACR122ReaderPlugin_0.2.jar)

I hope that helps! :)

Comment: The cgeers.wordpress.com link is invalid. Here is the correct one:
http://cgeers.com/2008/02/03/monitoring-a-smartcard-reader/